Zfs encrypted re-install width more swap
I already installed Ubuntu 24.04 with encrypted zfs partition but my swap partition has only 4Gb.
So I would to reinstall it with a swap partition of 30Gb.
Can I use the actual partitioning and just reduce the size of the zfs partition and increase the swap one before reinstalling?
